# ngrok 404 error with

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, ngrok

I'm working on ASP.NET Core application. I had to host online for testing few cases. I tried using ngrok. Everything perfectly done as show on:

[C# Corner link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/exposing-local-web-server-to-internet-using-ngrok/)

I could see the request being logged in ngrok 
But browser stops with 502 bad Gateway.

Comment: Can you give a little bit more details on what you are trying achieve? Why do you need ngrok? Are you having an external post request that you want to route to your local app?

Comment: I'm trying to use Facebook Crawler. To test it, I need to host my application on the internet first. Also, is there any alternative?